# Using PHP's composer for the first time

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to get my head around using PHP's composer. In particular, I'm trying to load this [project and its dependencies.](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php)

I am installing composer in the necessary folder (root of my application), so it creates a `composer.phar`.

I make sure I have the correct JSON file for the project in that same directory:

```
{

    "name": "tumblr/tumblr",

    "description": "Official Tumblr PHP Client",

    "keywords": ["tumblr", "api", "sdk", "gif"],

    "homepage": "https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php",

    "authors": [{
        "name": "John Crepezzi",
        "email": "john.crepezzi@gmail.com",
        "homepage": "https://github.com/seejohnrun",
        "role": "developer"
    }],

    "license": "Apache-2.0",

    "type": "library",

    "require": {
        "eher/oauth": "1.0.*",
        "guzzle/guzzle": ">=3.1.0,<4"
    },

    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Tumblr\\API": "lib"
        }
    }

}
```

I then write this in the appropriate directory with the terminal: `php composer.phar install`.

However, this does not load the `tumblr.php`. It loads other files, such as `symphony`, `sebastian`, `guzzle`, etc.

Am I doing this incorrectly? Does this JSON not load the `tumblr.php`, but its dependencies?

Comment: What do you expect to happen exactly? What does "load the tumblr.php" mean?

Comment: In the JSON, autoload says `"Tumblr\\API": "lib"` but there's no folder remotely called that in my `vendor` folder. Could this be because of an error, or is it because I misunderstand how composer works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer generates a file `vendor/autoload.php`. If you want to use any of the things you installed with Composer in your own code, you just need to `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'` and can then simply call whatever code in whatever Composer-installed library you want; the autoloader will take care of locating and including the necessary files without you having to worry about particular directories inside the `vendor` folder.

The `autoload` entry in the composer.json file is there so any library can specify particulars of how its files should be autoloaded. You do not typically have to use that yourself in your application for anything. You *may* use this entry to add autoloading for your own code "for free" if you wish. However, again, you do not need to add this to use any of the installed dependencies, those should all already be configured correctly for autoloading in their respective composer.json files.

Comment: Thanks. I also realised they were only loading dependencies, so I still had to load the master from Github. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON data you show is in your OWN project, you are doing it wrong. That JSON data is from the original Tumblr project, and you shouldn't copy it into your project, because as you found out, it will not really help you using the Tumblr client.

The correct way of using Composer:

1. Start your project by having a main directory (probably already with files).
2. Run `composer init` to easily create the initial `composer.json` file.
3. You will be asked if you want to include dependencies. You may answer yes and add `tumblr/tumblr` as the dependency of your project.

Alternatively, if you already have a `composer.json`, you can call `composer require tumblr/tumblr:~0.1`.

To use the library in your code, you have to include the file `vendor/autoload.php` and can then create all the classes according to the documentation.